# WPF - Is there something similar to PathCompactPath?

Tags: wpf, filepath

I would like to compact filepaths the same way that PathCompactPath does in Windows Forms, so when you stretch out the parent control, more of the filepath becomes visible and vice versa.

Since PathCompactPath uses character sizes, is there any similar in WPF that uses pixel sizes/dpi? Or a converter of some kind?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, IMHO PathCompactPath does not exist in Windows Forms. You would have to use PInvoke there.

Unfortunately this functionality is also not in WPF. The closest to what you need is [TextBlock.TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx). I also do not know of any 3rd party control that can do this. You yould however roll your own. Using [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx) (`.Width` and `.Height`) you can measure your string before you render it. You can also use it to actually render text.